# Small training set: is it an option to use artificially generated data?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling

I am working on a problem where I am trying to estimate the construction value of specific types of buildings. To this end, we have a (complex) mathematical formula (taking into account 15 variables) that is considered to yield the ground truth. At estimation time, however, not all of these variables are available, as the idea is to create a product where the end-user does not need to provide exact values for all these variables. Some variables will be dropped, others will be discretized for the user's convenience.

For this problem, I am currently using an ML approach. I have a dataset of 800 cases for which the exact values for each of the 15 variables is available. Given the formula, this allows me to calculate the exact construction value. Now, the problem that I am facing is twofold:

- I do not know whether the distribution of this dataset is representative of the cases I will be confronted with at estimation time.
- 800 cases is a relatively small sample to fit a complex function.

I have tried the most basic approach: k-fold cross-validation on the input dataset of 800 cases. This does have great results on this specific dataset, but, as indicated before, I'm weary that this does not generalize well outside of the space defined by the input dataset. (I have tested this on a set of 50K completely random (uniformly) samples, and indeed, the performance is quite bad.)

In my current approach, I have fitted the joint distribution (histogram-based) of the input dataset, allowing me to take random samples from it. My training set now consists of 5K samples from the joint distribution and 15K completely random (uniformly) samples. The idea was, essentially, to augment the joint distribution with a uniform prior, hoping that the resulting model would take into account the interactions (correlations) observed in the samples from the joint distribution, and be able to generalize well (outside of the original subspace) based on the presence of the completely random samples.
I have used this training set to train a LightGBM model and test it on different test sets (the original 800 cases, a test set based on the joint distribution and a completely random test set). The results seem satisfactory, but I am wondering whether this is considered a valid approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, this seems reasonable, although I am not 100% sure I understand all the details of the problem. For instance, if the 15 features are often not available, what are the features going into the ML model?

I would also check out [SMOTE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1813), which generates synthetic examples "between" known cases. I think this might provide similar results to your approach. Another option - if I understand the problem correctly - is to take observations with most of the 15 variables, interpolate the missing ones, and generate labels for those. Is that an option? Finally, I would just warn to be careful about the approach in general. Best case scenario, your ML model just recreates the complex mathematical formula. I'd be curious to hear more about the motivation behind using ML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To elaborate on the problem setting: the data in the original dataset (800 cases) is complete, i.e., all variables are available and exact values for continuous variables are known. However, the idea is to create a product where the end-user does not need to fill out all these details. Some variables will be dropped, others will be discretized (for the user's convenience). You could argue that one way of solving the problem, is to impute the missing values and use the formula. I am hoping that my approach does something similar with less effort (or more flexibility).

Comment: So is the ML framing "predict the construction value given the other 15 features"? If so, wouldn't you need to impute the missing values anyways to feed the model? Or do you have other features used in the ML step?

Comment: The construction value is always calculated using the exact values (both for the real data (800 cases) as all artificially created data). During the modeling phase the data is transformed: inconvenient (for the end-user) features are removed and continuous features are discretized. The model is then trained on the transformed data, but the goal is to predict the exact target.

Comment: ohh ok that makes more sense now. Just be careful with the "15K completely random (uniformly) samples", because you are implicitly forecasting those missing/inconvenient variables, and those artificial training observations may have unrealistic relationships. I'm tempted to say the joint distribution and SMOTE approaches are safer in that regard.

Comment: You're hitting the nail on the head :) That is exacly what concerns me most. On the one hand I'm thinking that the effect of the 'implicit forecasting' greatly depends on the number of removed features and the exact discretization process. On the other hand that is what I am trying to counteract with my current (mixed) approach (of course, the 5K/15K or just parameters that are liable to change). Thank you for the back and forth. I'll be sure to check out SMOTE as well!